# SICStus Prolog: statistics/2 values affected by JIT

Tags: prolog, benchmarking, sicstus-prolog

**Update:** As reported by @PerMildner, the below issue (present with SICStus Prolog 4.3.**2**) has vanished with the new SICStus Prolog 4.3.**3**! **Way to go!**

---

I'm using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2 and I'm
getting to know some of the [`statistics/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dmgc_002dove_002dsta.html) keys that I haven't used before... Here's my code:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

a_is_b_minus_c(A,B,C) :-
   A is B-C.

call_keys_deltas(Goal_0, Keys, Deltas) :-
   maplist(statistics, Keys, Values0),
   call(Goal_0),
   maplist(statistics, Keys, Values1),
   maplist(a_is_b_minus_c, Deltas, Values1, Values0).
```

`call_keys_deltas/3` gathers some information about the execution of predicates like:

```
boolsA([]).                        
boolsA([0|Bs]) :- boolsA(Bs).
boolsA([1|Bs]) :- boolsA(Bs).

%%

bool(0).
bool(1).

boolsB([]).
boolsB([B|Bs]) :- bool(B), boolsB(Bs).
```

I'm expecting two choicepoints for `?- boolsA([0,0]).`—but none for `?- boolsB([0,0]).`

The numbers I get immediately after the JIT ran differ from the ones I get once it is done:

- With JIT

  ```
  $ export SP_JIT=enabled && sicstus
  % ...
  | ?- call_keys_deltas(boolsA([0,0]), [choice_used,trail_used], Ds).
  Ds = [112,904] ? ;
  no
  | ?- call_keys_deltas(boolsA([0,0]), [choice_used,trail_used], Ds).
  Ds = [112,16] ? ;
  no
  | ?- call_keys_deltas(boolsB([0,0]), [choice_used,trail_used], Ds).
  Ds = [0,1264] ? ;
  no
  | ?- call_keys_deltas(boolsB([0,0]), [choice_used,trail_used], Ds).
  Ds = [0,8] ? ;
  no
  ```
- **Without** JIT

  ```
  $ export SP_JIT=disabled && sicstus
  % ...
  | ?- call_keys_deltas(boolsA([0,0]), [choice_used,trail_used], Ds).
  Ds = [112,16] ? ;
  no
  | ?- call_keys_deltas(boolsA([0,0]), [choice_used,trail_used], Ds).
  Ds = [112,16] ? ;
  no
  | ?- call_keys_deltas(boolsB([0,0]), [choice_used,trail_used], Ds).
  Ds = [0,8] ? ;
  no
  | ?- call_keys_deltas(boolsB([0,0]), [choice_used,trail_used], Ds).
  Ds = [0,8] ? ;
  no
  ```

I wonder if above discrepancy is intentional... Thank for your help!

Comment: That's the price for JIT-compilation

Comment: @false. I get that JIT does not come for free. OTOH I'm only a JIT user, so I probably should not get that statistics data unless I specifically ask for it using the right, documented interface for it.

Comment: @false. Of course, that wasn't the actual question I wanted to ask: "How to quantify non-determinacy"

Comment: Wild guess: add an explicit GC prior to taking those values.

Comment: The latest release of SICStus Prolog (4.3.3) no longer shows the above difference between first and subsequent calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference was not intentional. It should be gone in the latest release of SICStus Prolog (4.3.3).

Note that the `choice_used` did not differ, even before SICStus 4.3.3, and that statistic is probably what you should use in order to "quantify non-determinacy".